# Jersey cannot deserialize java.util.UUID out of String in request object

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jersey

I have an endpoint which accepts a `DriverJson` class instance as http request payload. The `DriverJson` class has a property `userId` which is of type `java.util.UUID`. 
The problem is that Jersey cannot deserialize `UUID` string into `UUID` object. When I debug and inspected `driverJson`, `userId1` property is `null` (luckily it does not throw exception). I have read this article ([article](https://www.geekmj.org/jersey/jax-rs-java-type-consume-request-parameter-values-guide-352/)) that explains that classes that have `fromString(String string)` method (`java.util.UUID` has it) or have constructor with one (`String`) argument  are deserialized by Jersey automatically (without writing any additional deserializer classes). If I change `UUID` type to `String` and I convert it my self (`UUID.fromString(userId)`) it's working perfectly.

In addition I use a `@PathParam UUID` arguments in some of my endpoints and they are working perfectly (as expected).

Below is my code:

My resource endpoint:

```
@POST
public Response add(DriverJson driverJson) {
    DriverJson driver = service.add(driverJson);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(driver).build();
}
```

My Driver class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DriverJson {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private UUID userId;

    public DriverJson() {}

    public DriverJson(UUID id, String name, UUID userId){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    /// getters & setters /////////

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UUID getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(UUID userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

My JSON request object:

```
{
  "name" : "John", 
  "userId" : "ff06c5a4-135c-40b7-83f3-3648ec035efc"
}
```

I am using the standard Jersey archetype (version 2.23.2) with the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.50</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*AFAIK* you can fix it by using custom [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html):

```java
public class UUIDAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, UUID> {

    @Override
    public UUID unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return UUID.fromString(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(UUID v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }
}
```

And then mark your fields with [`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) annotation

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class DriverJson {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UUIDAdapter.class)
    private UUID id;
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UUIDAdapter.class)
    private UUID userId;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works, but I don't understand why I have to write custom adapters when Jersey should know how to deserialize it out of the box? I also don't understand how Jersey can deserialize String @PathParam to UUID, but when comes to request objects, it can't?

Comment: @anchor my solution applies to `jaxb` which is unable to convert `UUID` from/to `String` by default. `@PathParam` works because it is not processed by `jaxb` but by `jersey` itself. But this is only [one possible way](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e8052) to marshal `JSON` data. I'm not sure but guess that there is some misconfiguration between `jersey` and `jaxb`. You can try  to switch to `jackson` serilalization (`jersey-media-json-jackson` package) which *afaik* is able to handle `UUID` out of the box.